# ButtonClickListener cannot converted to OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

What is the problem in this code? It's not working: it gives 2 errors.

1. error: cannot find symbol class onClickListener
2. error: incompatible types: MainActivity.ButtonClickListener cannot be converted to OnClickListener

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scr =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView );

    int idList[] ={R.id.button ,R.id.button2, R.id.button3,R.id.button4,R.id.button5,R.id.button6,R.id.button7,R.id.button8,R.id.button9,R.id.buttonC,R.id.buttonAdd,
            R.id.buttonSub,R.id.buttonEq};

    for (int id:idList){
        View v =(View) findViewById(id);
        v.setOnClickListener(btnclick);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void nMath(String str)
{
   number1 =Float.parseFloat(scr.getText().toString());
    op =str;
   scr.setText("0");
}

public void getkeyboard(String str)
{
    String ScrCurrent =scr.getText().toString();
    if(ScrCurrent.equals("0"))
        ScrCurrent ="";
    ScrCurrent +=scr;
    scr.setText(ScrCurrent);
}

public void nResult( ){
    float number2 =Float.parseFloat(scr.getText().toString());
    float result = 0;
    if(op.equals("+"))
    {
        result =number1 + number2;
    }
    if(op.equals("-"))
    {
        result =number1 - number2;
    }
    scr.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}

private class ButtonClickListener implements onClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonC:
             scr.setText("0");
                number1 = 0;
                op ="";
                break;
            case R.id.buttonAdd:
                nMath("+");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSub:
                nMath("-");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonEq:
                nResult();
            default:
                String num =((Button) v).getText().toString();
                getkeyboard(num);
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: `OnClickListener` not `onClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Java class names are capitalized:

```
private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
```